# SQL Server query update child node based on parent records

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to query data with the following structure in a SQL Server table 
'tableA' with column 'node' (varchar) and 'destination' (bit). The data in the node column is based on parent/child relationship. Row child: 1001111001 has all these rows/nodes as parents (100111100, 10011110, 1001111, 100111, 10011, 1001, 100, 10, 1). I would like to accomplish the following in a store procedure on sql server

1- Retrieve all parents of a child node.

2- Update destination of child row if all parent destination are equal to 0

Answer (score 0):

try this:::

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UP_PROCEURENAME
@tablename varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @cnt INT = 1
 WHILE @cnt < len(destination)
 (select left(destination, len(destination)-@cnt) AS Parents from @tablename
 set @cnt = @cnt + 1)
 END LOOP
 GO
 IF(LEFT(destination,LEN(destination)-1) = 0)
   UPDATE @tablename
   SET destination =   ------YOUR UPDATE STATEMENT
END

EXEC UP_PROCEURENAME TableA
```

Comment: The query above does not work. You are looping while len(destination)? destination has a bit datatype.

Comment: actually you cannot use bit as a datatype for your particular binary strings. Bit holds only one digit. either 0 or 1. if you input digits other than 0, it casts your data as '1', else 0. change the datatype for "destination" column........... @ibrahim

Comment: The node column which is a varchar contains the (100111100, 10011110, 1001111, 100111, 10011, 1001, 100, 10, 1) data

Comment: if you could provide a sample data from your table, that'd help me a lot to figure out the problem.

Comment: tableA(node, destination) Rows (100111100, 0) (10011, 0) (251, 0) (10011110, 0) (1001, 1) (10, 0) (2510, 0) (100, 1) (25104, 0) (10014, 0) (100140, 0) (25103, 0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1 AS Num,
    Left(@S, ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1) as ParentNode,
    t.Destination as ParentDestination
FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
         (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n),
         (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) hundreds(n),
         tableA t 
WHERE ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n BETWEEN 0 AND Len(@s)-2 AND t.Node = Left(@S, ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1)
ORDER BY ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n
```

as for update, you can now check if SUM of all parent destinations = 0